# Scroll to manipulate the TableView, erases the contents of the TextField created in table

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I put the numbers in my textfields located in Mirror column, But when I handle the scroll bar (scroll my table), the contents of the textfields are deleted. Is there any solution to this problem?

The code that creates my table:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
private void loadTabMirror() {


    TableColumn request = new TableColumn("Pedido");
    request.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MirrorVo, String>("request"));
    request.setMinWidth(150);

    TableColumn applicant = new TableColumn("Requerente");
    applicant.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MirrorVo, String>("name"));
    applicant.setMinWidth(400);


    TableColumn numberRg = new TableColumn("N° RG");
    numberRg.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MirrorVo, String>("rg"));
    numberRg.setMinWidth(80);

    Callback<TableColumn<MirrorVo, String>, TableCell<MirrorVo, String>> txtMirrorCallBack = 
            new Callback<TableColumn<MirrorVo, String>, TableCell<MirrorVo, String>>() {

        @Override
        public TableCell call(final TableColumn param) {
            final TableCell cell = new TableCell() {

                @Override
                public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if (empty) {
                        setText(null);
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else if(item == null){
                        TextField textField = loadRuleTextField(param,getIndex()); 
                        textFieldMirrors.add(textField);
                        setGraphic(textField);
                        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

                    } 
                }
            };
            return cell;
        }
    };

    TableColumn mirror = new TableColumn("Espelho"); 
    mirror.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MirrorVo, Integer>("mirror"));
    mirror.setMinWidth(100);
    mirror.setCellFactory(txtMirrorCallBack);

    Callback<TableColumn<MirrorVo, String>, TableCell<MirrorVo, String>> imgMirrorInfo = 
            new Callback<TableColumn<MirrorVo, String>, TableCell<MirrorVo, String>>() {

                @Override
                public TableCell<MirrorVo, String> call(
                        TableColumn<MirrorVo, String> param) {

                    final TableCell cell = new TableCell() {

                        @Override
                        public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
                            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                            if (empty) {
                                setText(null);
                                setGraphic(null);
                            } else {
                                ImageView imgViewInfo = new ImageView(new Image("resources/img/info.png"));
                                imgViewInfo.setFitWidth(32);
                                imgViewInfo.setFitHeight(32);
                                imgViewInfo.setVisible(false);
                                imgViewInfos.put(getIndex(), imgViewInfo);
                                setGraphic(imgViewInfo);
                                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    return cell;
                }

    };

    TableColumn info = new TableColumn("Status");
    info.setMinWidth(40);
    info.setCellFactory(imgMirrorInfo);

    Callback<TableColumn<CivilRecord, String>, TableCell<CivilRecord, String>> btnInvalidateCallBack = addActionBtnInvalidate();

    TableColumn validation = new TableColumn(" ");
    validation.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<CivilRecord, String>("dateRegisterLot"));
    validation.setMinWidth(100);
    validation.setCellFactory(btnInvalidateCallBack);


    Callback<TableColumn<CivilRecord, String>, TableCell<CivilRecord, String>> btnAutoGenerateCallBack = addActionBtnAutoGenerate();

    TableColumn autoGenerate = new TableColumn(" ");
    autoGenerate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<CivilRecord, String>("dateRegisterLot"));
    autoGenerate.setMinWidth(100);
    autoGenerate.setCellFactory(btnAutoGenerateCallBack);

    tabMirror.getColumns().addAll(request,applicant,numberRg,mirror,info,autoGenerate, validation);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `TableCell` for the `mirror` column never actually handles the case where the item has content (i.e. the item is not null).

As you scroll, what probably happens is that `TableCell`s which are scrolled off the visible portion of the screen get updated as empty cells, then they get reused at some point for new items that are displayed. So the `updateItem()` method is first called with `empty=true` (setting the text and graphic to `null`), and is later called with `empty=false` and `item` as the item to be displayed. Since your `updateItem` method doesn't handle this case at all, the cell's text and graphic remain null.

You need to change the `updateItem` method so that it handles all possible cases:

- `empty == true` (you already have)
- `empty == false && item == null` (you already have)
- `empty == false && item != null` (you do not handle)